# Get Windows 10 Blank Screen

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-10-upgrade

I am running Windows 7 and have the Get Windows 10 icon show up in my taskbar.  When I open it up, I just get a blank screen.  That has not been a problem because I have the Windows 10 CD that I was going to use when I was ready to upgrade (some programs I need to use are not compatible yet).  However, I have also noticed today that H&R block software that I just purchased has a similar issue.  When I start the program, I don't get the registration page like what shows up on this video at 5:35 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPN_LAF6M74&t=5m35s).  When looking at both of these issues together, it appears like they could be related.  Both programs look like they are trying to run a browser from within the program and that is where it fails.

I have reset my IE settings in the Advanced tab and that did not fix the issue.  I also created a new user on my computer and when I do that, both the Get Windows 10 screen shows up correctly and the H&R Block program works with that new user.

Any ideas on what setting on my main account could be the cause of this issue?  I can use the test account for H&R Block and upgrade to Windows 10 using the CD as I was planning, but it would be more convenient to not have to use that second account.

Comment: Any solution I have would involve installing Windows again Windows 7 does not have the required tools to repair th type of damage you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have gone through quite a bit of troubleshooting and have found a fix to my issue.  What I did was create two new accounts on my machine.  After I did this I used Windows Easy Transfer to copy my settings from my main account to one of the new accounts.  This caused the new account to break the same way my main account was breaking.  I then loaded the two NTUSER.dat files for the new accounts (located in C:\Users\USERNAME) into the registry when in my main account.  Once I had these setup, I used Beyond Compare to go through and compare the registry and bit by bit I copied from the working account to the non-working account until I the non-working account was fixed.  Doing this (several times) I was able to narrow down the problem to what seemed to be an extra zone key (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones) that had a name of just the ascii character for end of text (ascii value of 3).  After deleting this key, everything is working fine for me.